# fullscreen gallery advice

Tags: javascript, background, gallery, fullscreen, slideshow

I'm in need of some advice on Fullscreen gallery plugins.

I'm building a fullscreen gallery. And I want to have it scroll through projects, then within each project are a range images relating to that project.

I need the next and previous buttons to scroll through the projects, then a small navigation panel at the bottom scroll through the images within the project.

Does anyone know of any plugins that will help me achieve this? Or any websites that utilize a gallery of this nature, that I can study?

Any help would be much appreicated.

I'd even be willing to pay someone to develop it for me. As it is for a commercial project.

Thanks,
Josh.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/ this a great jQuery photo gallery website.

Here you can find number of free photo gallery plugins with code and you can modify as well. Each plugin is very easy to use and customize. Documentation and help also available for all plugins.

***[Check it out](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/).***